# Using a C# regex to parse a domain name?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to parse the domain name from a string. The string can vary and I need the exact domain.

Examples of Strings:

```
http://somename.de/
www.somename.de/
somename.de/
somename.de/somesubdirectory
www.somename.de/?pe=12
```

I need it in the following format with just the domain name, the `tld`, and the `www`, if applicable:

```
www.somename.de
```

How do I do that using C#?

Comment: hey thanks for making it more clear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i simple used

```
 Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/search?q=439489");
            string url = uri.Host.ToString();
            return url;
```

because by using this you can sure.

Comment: Can't be so sure though, your solution also accepts "h t t p : / / h t t p : / /yee" as a correct url (without the spaces, but stackoverflow changes the double http:// into one...

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative to a regex solution, you can let the `System.Uri` class parse the string for you. You just have to make sure the string contains a scheme.

```
string uriString = "http://www.google.com/search";

if (!uriString.Contains(Uri.SchemeDelimiter))
{
    uriString = string.Concat(Uri.UriSchemeHttp, Uri.SchemeDelimiter, uriString);
}

string domain = new Uri(uriString).Host;
```

This solution also filters out any port numbers and converts IPv6 addresses to its canonical form.

Comment: Your answers looks valid also.

Comment: @AbdulSaboor, what would you expect? The URL contains a host name with a space in it (" blabla") which makes it an invalid host name. Just the "http://" is also an invalid URL. The `Uri` constructor expects a valid URL.

Comment: 1. It says the valid url if I remove the space. 2. i tried with only blabla still it says it is valid url. I think it should not.

Answer (score 2):

I checked out [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=domain%20name), and it looks like something like this might work for you:

```
^(([\w][\w\-\.]*)\.)?([\w][\w\-]+)(\.([\w][\w\.]*))?$
```

Comment: @Umair Ashraf - you should probably explain how it doesn't work. Can you give an example of a line it doesn't match?

Comment: I straight put this line in Regex connstructor like (@"^(([\w][\w\-\.]*)\.)?([\w][\w\-]+)(\.([\w][\w\.]*))?$")

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(?:\w+://)?([^/?]*)
```

this is a weak regex - it doesn't validate the string, but assumes it's already a url, and gets the first word, until the first slash, while ignoring the protocol. To get the domain look at the first captured group, for example:

```
string url = "http://www.google.com/hello";
Match match = Regex.Match(url, @"^(?:\w+://)?([^/?]*)");
string domain = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

As a bonus, it also captures until the first `?`, so the url `google.com?hello=world` will work as expected.