# Regex extraction of URL

Tags: c#, regex

for example, I have:

```
String a = abcd http//google.com abcd
```

and

```
String b=efgh http//yahoomail.hey.com ihklm
```

How can I extract only the words:

```
google
yahoomail.hey
TIA
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325796/1849024

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        string pattern = @"//[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[.][a-zA-z]{2,4}";
        string input = @"http//yahoomail.hey.com ihklm";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", m.Value.ToString().Replace("/",""));
        }
```

Explaination:

// The match needs to start with "//"

[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,} next there can be any amount of characters specified in[ ] 1 to n times

[.] then there needs to be a .

[a-zA-z]{2,4} the domain can be any Upper/lower character and there need to be at least 2 but max 4 characters

to check your Regexes, i suggest using https://regex101.com/
use the standard settingswith PHP flavour. after you are finished creating the Regex, you can use "Code generator" on the left to convert it to JScript/php/python/c#/java/ruby/rust/perl/golang

Comment: why if I tried searching this  <add key="aweaws" value="http://ho-awedead.dead.prod> it doesnt return anything. i want to get anthing in between http:// and .prod only

Comment: @Est, This is what [mcve] is for! Every case should be in your test input in your question, with it's expected result.

Comment: @DanilEroshenko You could change that, but you dont need to. Est's examples show, that he dont want to have the http:// in front of it. 
The pattern will match "//yahoomail.hey", the Replace will get "yahoomail.hey"